# ¿Cómo controlar la URL cuando se escribe desde js?

Tags: javascript

Tengo montada una SPA con el *hash* (#) pero me gustaría cambiarla para no tener que ponerlo.

Me va bien con el `onpopstate` hasta que el usuario escribe la URL.
Por ejemplo, cuando estoy en `/page/about` y el usuario escribe `/page/home` ya no va y he visto el `onbeforeunload`,  pero no me funciona y no sé por qué.

Tengo que se cargue en la SPA la URL por defecto si no pone la página.

```
  urlChange = (event: Event) => {
    const routeName = this.location.pathname;
    event.preventDefault();
    const route = this.routes[routeName]
      ? this.routes[routeName]
      : this.routes[DEFAULT_ROUTE_NAME];
    this.gotToRoute(route);
  };
```

La función `urlChange` es una función de la clase que maneja la vista y es la que tiene las rutas de las demá. Quiero que se ejecute cuando se dé el evento para cancelar el cambio de página. `routes` es un *array* que como *key* utilizo su *path*.

Comment: Esto no es javascript puro, debes agregar el framework que estas usando.

Comment: puedes implementar un router simple. Hay muchos tutoriales, tambien paquetes npm. Aqui tienes uno por si quieres ver https://medium.com/javascript-by-doing/create-a-modern-javascript-router-805fc14d084d

Comment: Por lo único que no es javascript es por el tipado de typescript. Por lo demás es igual en esa función. Es que lo estoy intentandolo hacer sin paquetes pero gracias puede que lo utilice en otro proyecto